# CFBundleLocalizations info.plist - How to put multiple languages

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, info.plist

I cannot find the answer for this question anywhere. I'm new to Xcode. I have developed two multilanguage iPhone apps and cannot upload them to iTunes Connect because I'm getting the famous error "the value for the info.plist key cfbundlelocalizations is not of the required type for that key". Everybody says that it's because I need to put there an array of values, but I don't know how to do it. If I need for example, English and French, what should I to put there? Something like this (0=en, 1=fr)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The plist editor in Xcode seems to insist that it should be a string... if you want an array, try opening the plist file in a text editor, and adding this after a value:

```
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>English</string>
        <string>French</string>
    </array>
```

so your plist would look like this:

```
...
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>     
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>English</string>
        <string>French</string>
    </array>
...
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I could upload my app to iTunes Connect, thanks again. Please vote down for the other answer that other people let, it's not the answer for this question.

Comment: This will not work. You must use ISO 639-1 or ISO 639-2 language code names instead like @mojomajor specified in his answer

Comment: @justin: I don't know if that was the old situation, but now I only see `en`, `fr` strings like Softlion mentioned. Please correct/update your answer!

Comment: Documentation says that you can use both: “Each entry in this property’s array is a string identifying the language name or ISO language designator of the supported localization”. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-109552

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add German with English like so:

Changed:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
```

To:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
  <string>en</string>
  <string>de</string>
</array>
```