# CFBundleDisplayName localization doesn't work

Tags: ios7, localization

I'm trying to localize my app name, but can't get it working. I've got a localized InfoPlist.strings with the following content:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Application Name in English";
CFBundleName = "App Name – in English";
```

as well as the `LSHasLocalizedDisplayName` (`Application has localized Display Name`) set to `YES`. What else could I be missing?

What could I be missing? In another app it works seemlessly, but for this one app I can't get the name to be localized.

InfoPlist.strings is in the same directory as the other localized strings and the target Membership is selected as well.

**EDIT**: as I found out, I've got two langauages (german, english) and it works for german, but not for english... the app locatization (localizable.strings) in the same en-directory works perfect, but the InfoPlist.strings doesn't...

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this on the device or in the simulator?

Because in the simulator it will always run in English (or maybe your Macs language, which is English for me), it will not take the settings from the simulator itself.

It's weird, but you need to adjust the language for the app at compile time in the scheme:

[image]

Comment: Nice Catch. That can certainly be an issue. +1

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but if anyone is not seeing your app name being localized on an iOS device, even though you edited the target's scheme for the language, that's because it will *only* be displayed if you change the device's language directly (in Settings / General / Language & Region).

Comment: Thank you ! I kept wondering why it wouldn't show up until I changed the device's language in settings. Worked perfectly after that

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you have added `CFBundleDisplayName` & `CFBundleName` in `InfoPlist.string`. Is there any possibility, that you might not have it in `info.plist` file.

Also, You might want to check if the followings are not returning `null`:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey];
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleLocalizationsKey];
```

And also, (You must have read it, but still) I have a doubt that this can be an issue, if you can check.

> Before displaying a localized name for your bundle, the Finder
>   compares the value of this key against the actual name of your bundle
>   in the file system. If the two names match, the Finder proceeds to
>   display the localized name from the appropriate InfoPlist.strings file
>   of your bundle. If the names do not match, the Finder displays the
>   file-system name.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing CFBundleLocalizations values, but added them with help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350151/cfbundlelocalizations-info-plist-how-to-put-multiple-languages (note that the array values should be language codes such as en, es, etc.)